# How to make the toast on android appear until user touch the screen?

Tags: android

I have toast that i want to display to the user. How to make the toast on android appear until user touch screen?

Comment: A standard Toast does not provide this functionality. You would have to implement it on your own.

Comment: Use a Dialog instead

Comment: or use relativelayout->textview set rounded corner background to relativelayout and make visible untile user clicks the screen

Comment: use INDEFINITE Snackbar instead of Toast

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37835

Answer (score 1):

```
   RelativeLayout layy;
    layy = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);
    layy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

create layout which fill the screen and set onclicklistener to this layout,hope this will help.
I checked and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Toast doesn't work like that they appear for a limited time, for this purpose you can use Snackbar from widget design support library or you can make a custom AlertDialog.

```
Snackbar snackBar = new Snackbar(activity,
                "Are you sure?",
                "Yes",
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ButtonFlat btn = (ButtonFlat) findViewById(R.id.buttonSnackBar);
                        
                    }
                });
        snackBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        snackBar.show();
```